# Draw an approximation curve for a given data points in Opencv

Tags: opencv, polynomial-approximations

Is Opencv is capable of drawing an approximation curve for given data points which might have noise? Do I need to implement that approximation function separately?

Comment: do you want to DRAW the (known) curve or du you want to COMPUTE the curve? To draw a known parametric curve, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526617/trying-to-plot-simple-function-using-opencv-c/24527147#24527147 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590329/access-to-pixels-along-the-curve-path-using-opencv/20710629#20710629 . To approximate points by a curve, see `cv::fitLine`, `approxPolyDP` etc. but probably there are better libraries to fit curves, because openCV is about computer vision.

Comment: What is the approximate noise ratio ?

Answer (score 0):

No.
You need to implement the approximation function separately. Take the data points and fit a polynomial curve using standard least squares/ total least squares approximation. You can also use RANSAC algorithm, if you have a high number of outliers in the data.